# How to perform .tap() after duration under UITests in XCode 7?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, xcode-ui-testing

Is it possible to **tap the button after some time interval**?

Simply, I want to perform `logoutButton.tap()` on button that **EXISTS** after 2 seconds.

Comment: Can't you just put sleep(2.0) in your test and then tap the button ?

Answer (score -1):

It's simple. Just use `waitForExpectationsWithTimeout`

```
let exists = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true")

expectationForPredicate(exists, evaluatedWithObject: view, handler: nil)
waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(5, handler: nil)
```

Comment: The problem is that my object always exists. And it is evaluated immediately. Your code doesn't mean that it will be done after 5 seconds, but once after predicate is true. In my case after 0 seconds.